# How to add play pause images to react-native-media-controls

Tags: react-native, custom-controls

Can we add custom images to react-native-media-controls? In the documentation, nothing mention about adding custom images. It's possible to change the color but nothing mention about custom images. Is there anyone know about this, pls share your thoughts.

Many Thanks 
[image]